# Curly braces in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In react native render function, I've tried writing something like:

```
render(){
  return (
    <View>
      {let a=5}
    </View>
  )
}
```

I thought I can write there any JS code, but it seems that it's an error.
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Any reason why you can't move {let a=5} up above the return statement?  Also, in React Native you have to embed any actual output inside of a <Text></Text> block (different than web React).

Comment: it is a theoretical question. Wanted to understand what can be added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not related to ReactNative, but to JSX syntax.

You can only [embed expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx). 
`let a=5` is not an expression but an assignment, try to execute `(let a = 5)` in your browser console, you will see an error.
You have to declare your variables above your JSX.

```
render(){
   let a = 5;
   return (
     <View>
      {/* use `a` here */}
     </View>
   )
}
```